# Drop down sub category menu positioning.

Tags: html, css

I've been asked to fix a menu on a client's website as the website's 4th sub menu doesn't pop up next to the link. The website is https://www.abrimagery.com/store/ If you go to Borosilicate Flameworking > 33 COE Borosilicate Flameworking > 33 COE Color Rod Frit and Tubing > ACME Color Glass, you'll see what I mean. The sub menu pops up in a fixed location and you can't mouse over to it. I was able to change the positioning to relative and the menu would pop out next to the link, however it would leave a blank space under the link. After some research, I found that's how relative positioning works. Can someone look at this and point me in the right direction as I'm in over my head. I'm tried searching google and found some documentation for the store template, but it wasn't helpful at all. I'm a hardware tech at an MSP who was asked if I could fix this because I had mentioned I took a few web design classes in college. I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
#drop-box, .drop-box-subcat, .drop-box-subsubcat, .drop-box-3subcat, .drop-box-4subcat{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
z-index:100;
display: none;
text-align:left;
padding:0;
top:57px;
border: none;
width:auto;
background: #fbfbfb;
padding:20px 15px 20px 15px;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 10px 15px 2px #727272;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 10px 15px 2px #727272 ;
box-shadow:  0px 10px 15px 2px #727272 ;

}

.drop-box-subsubcat, .drop-box-3subcat, .drop-box-4subcat{left:200px;top:-7px;}
.drop-box-4subcat{top:50px;}

.cat-name, .sub-cat-name, .subsub-cat-name{
display: block;
float:left;
position:relative;
left:0px;
top:0px;
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try applying this to the `.drop-box-4subcat`

```
.drop-box-4subcat {
   top: inherit;
   margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Hope it helps with the other 4th category dropdowns as well!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use pixel for left positing of your sub menu. Change below css rule in file unishop.css line 683.

```
.drop-box-subsubcat, .drop-box-3subcat, .drop-box-4subcat {
    left: calc(100% + 15px);
    top: -7px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, that didn't have any affect on the 4th sub category. It moved all menu's to the right to where I can't mouse over to them.